# Как считать данные из файла

Tags: файлы, mvc, c++, visual-c++

Подскажите, как считать данные из файла. Читал, что написано про диалог на MSDN, но там не указано, как именно считывать данные.

Написал вот так:

```
{
    Stream^ myStream;
    if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
        {
            StreamReader^ sw = gcnew StreamReader(this->openFileDialog1->FileName);
            a = sw->Read();
            b = sw->Read();
            h = sw->Read();
            String^ s = "Левая граница: " + System::Convert::ToString(a) + "\n"
                + "Правая граница: " + System::Convert::ToString(b) + "\n"
                "Шаг: " + System::Convert::ToString(h) + "\n"
                "Ответ: ";
            for(float x = a; x < b; x += h)
            {
                if(x * x - sin(3 * x * 3.14159265 / 180) <= 0.00001)
                    s += System::Convert::ToString(int(x + 0.5));
            }
            MessageBox::Show(s, "Результат");
            myStream->Close();
            sw->Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Но вместо нужного результата (файл содержит `-2 0 2`), я получаю значения `45 50 32`.

Пробовал разные кодировки файлов (ANSI, UTF-8).

Comment: @elfinorr, чтобы код не нужно выкладывать скриншотом. Скопируйте его сюда и нажмите кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: это не `с++` это `c++-cli`

Answer (score 3):

Всё дело в конвертировании результата - он выдаёт не строку, а цифровое представление, - надо открывать файл как текстовый.